# Spring boot. Cannot authenticate with token

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing **OAuth2** *authorization grant* flow. 
When logging in through the Login page, the user is able to receive an access token. However, when I pass the access token to call an endpoint, which requires authentication, it triggers an exception.

Here are some logs:

```
 |2017-08-05 22:37:54.102  INFO 18809 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter
 chain:
 org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher@7efa3f63,
 [
 org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7134b8a7,
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3ff54f3d,
 org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7b61bf11,
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@18b74ea,
 org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter@1665fa54,
 org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@14c93774,
 org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@62a68bcb,
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2262d6d5,
 org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@40247d48,
 org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@315105f,
 org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@70025b99]
```

As you can see, there is an `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` in the chain.

However, when I call an endpoint, I get the following log:

```
.808 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.808 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.808 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2017-08-05 23:14:24.808 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2017-08-05 23:14:24.808 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.809 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@7091e577
2017-08-05 23:14:24.809 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users' doesn't match 'POST /login
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID 82C8AE1B7613B93D9F52F5A09CA5D114 is invalid.
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.810 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /users at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.811 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /users' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-08-05 23:14:24.811 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/users'; against '/resources/**'
2017-08-05 23:14:24.811 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /users; Attributes: [authenticated]
2017-08-05 23:14:24.814 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Sat Aug 05 23:14:24 CEST 2017, principal=<unknown>, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException, message=An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext}]
2017-08-05 23:14:24.817 DEBUG 19570 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point
```

And as you can see in the second log, it did not go through `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

And here is my security configuration:

```
public class SecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and().anonymous().disable();
   }
}
```

Does anybody know what might be the reason?
Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

Here is my configuration:
https://gist.github.com/osgafarov/ef432de739f0e8dd2eb595c0c75aff1d

Here is how I call the endpoint:

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer eaee916e-fdf1-4e80-808e-cfd9b2944539" localhost:8080/users
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have figured out that if I set

```
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3
```

then the above command works, however with this setting when I call `/oauth/authorize`, I receive the following error:
"Full authentication is required to access this resource. Unauthorized".

Comment: Are you using the `OAuth2RestTemplate` to get the resource?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza, nope

Comment: Then show how you are trying to access the endpoint. Does that endpoint belong to a resource server?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza, I have updated the post. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and resolved as follows, you need to configure resource server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/api/**", "/secured_area/**")
                // etc. add more matchers
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore).resourceId("myapp");
    }

}
```

Also as of spring boot 1.5.1+ i believe, security filter orders changed, you might want to overide the order:

```
 @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
 public class SecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { ..... }
```

Comment: But with this approach, when I call `/oauth/authorize`, I receive the following error: "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"

Comment: not sure how your code look like, but thats based on the link to your original code in github

Comment: How are you making the /oauth/authorize call?